# Euler18 dynamic algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math

Given the array [5, 4, 12, 3, 11, 7, 2, 8, 1, 9] that forms a triangle like so:

```
   5
  4 12
 3 11 7
2 8  1 9
```

Result should be 5 + 12 + 7 + 9 = 31.

Write a function that will traverse the triangle and find the largest possible sum of values when you can go from one point to either directly bottom left, or bottom right.

Refering to the dynamic algorithm in that link:
http://www.mathblog.dk/project-euler-18/

Result is 36.

```
  5
 4 12
 3 11 7
2 8 1 9

    5
   4 12
 11 19 16

  5
23 31

36
```

Where is my mistake ??

Comment: The maximum possible sum is `36`, not `31`. Going by path `5->12->11->8`.

Comment: @Rahul as far as I understood, stepping on 11 isn't allowed. Am I correct? you can't zig-zag until the bottom.

Comment: No, you understood the question wrong. From any point, you can go to left-down or right-down. So, yes you can zig-zag until the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [description of Problem 18](https://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=018) starts with an example where the optimal path is “left-right-right”. So you get a new choice of direction after every step, which means that after taking the first step to the right, you are still free to take the second step to the left and eventually come up with 5+12+11+8=36 as the optimal solution in your example, larger than the 31 you assumed. So the computation is correct in solving the problem as described. Your assumption about choosing a direction only once and then sticking with that choice would lead to a different (and rather boring) problem.